# How To Store Record's In WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7

i Just in windowsphone . i want store data as record in WP . i don't want manage file manually.

i want know is it something like sqlserver for windowsphone to store record's and Retrieval thats

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in [SQL CE database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28VS.92%29.aspx). You can also use third party databases such as [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) and [SQLite](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/) if you prefer (there are multiple `SQLite` wrappers available).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local database in Windows Phone since Mango update.

Please refer to [this tutorial](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database%28SQL-CE%29-Introduction) for a full how-to.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add(settingName, value);` to store the value in the Phone application...